# Mongodb find subdocument all values

Tags: mongodb

I want to find all the values from a subdocument like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("XXXXXXXXXXXX"), "consumers" : { "AAAAAAAA" : { "CLIENT" : { "AA" : true } } }, "country" : "ES", "history" : [ ], "last_time_updated" : ISODate("2014-11-28T13:32:19.948Z"), "msisdn" : "123", "operator" : "ES", "time_created" : ISODate("2014-11-28T13:32:19.948Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("XXXXXXXXXXXX"), "consumers" : { "AAAAAAAA" : { "CLIENT" : { "BB" : true } } }, "country" : "ES", "history" : [ ], "last_time_updated" : ISODate("2014-11-28T13:32:19.971Z"), "msisdn" : "123", "operator" : "ES", "time_created" : ISODate("2014-11-28T13:32:19.971Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("XXXXXXXXXXXX"), "consumers" : { "AAAAAAAA" : { "CLIENT" : { "CC" : false } } }, "country" : "ES", "history" : [ ], "last_time_updated" : ISODate("2014-11-28T13:32:19.977Z"), "msisdn" : "123", "operator" : "ES", "time_created" : ISODate("2014-11-28T13:32:19.977Z") }
```

That include all the values from "CLIENT" that i don't know, i am triying with:

```
db.collection.find({"consumers" : { "AAAAAAAA" : { "CLIENT" : { $exists : true } } }})
```

But is not a valid query, please some help?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dot notation can be used to match by fields in a sub document.

```
db.collection.find({"consumers.AAAAAAAA.CLIENT": {"$exists":true}})
```